# Swift 4 get song for every channel

Tags: json, swift, internet-radio

I got the same error when I try to get previous and song that play right now for every channel. I think something is wrong in my struct Root and playlist because data is not in the correct format.I am using Swift 4 and trying to learn JSON, but its hard. Previous struct is same as Song struct. How do I fix my error?

My code looks now:

```
  import UIKit

    struct Root : Decodable {
        let copyright : String
        let channels : [Channel]
        let pagination : Pagination



    }

    struct Channel : Decodable {
        let image : String
        let imagetemplate : String
        let color : String
        let tagline : String?
        let siteurl : String
        let id : Int
        let url : URL?
        let statkey : String?
        let scheduleurl : String
        let channeltype : String
        let name : String
    }

    struct Pagination : Decodable {
        let page, size, totalhits, totalpages : Int
        let nextpage : URL
    }

    struct  Playlist : Decodable{
        let id : Int
        let name :String
        let prev : [previoussong]
        let song : [Song]
    }
    struct previoussong : Decodable  {
        let  title : String
        let description : String
        let artist : String
        let composer :String
        let conductor : String
        let albumname : String
        let recordlabel : String
        let lyricist : String
        let producer : String
        let starttimeutc : String
        let stopttimeutc : String

    }
    struct Song : Decodable  {
        let  title : String
        let description : String
        let artist : String
        let composer :String
        let conductor : String
        let albumname : String
        let recordlabel : String
        let lyricist : String
        let producer : String
        let starttimeutc : String
        let stopttimeutc : String

    }
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {
        var auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()!
        var session:SPTSession!
        var loginUrl: URL?
    var tests = [Channel]()
    //var pl = [Playlist]()
        var stationsName:String?

        @IBOutlet weak var tableV: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var statLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var songLabel: UILabel!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            tableV.dataSource = self

            downloadStations()




        }
        func downloadStations(){
            let test2 = "http://api.sr.se/api/v2/channels?format=json"
            let play = "http://api.sr.se/api/v2/playlists/rightnow?format=json"

            let url = URL(string: test2)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data , response, error) in
               do{
                let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
                self.tests = root.channels
                for eachStations in self.tests {
                    self.stationsName = eachStations.name
                    print(" " + self.stationsName!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        self.tableV.reloadData()
                    }
    }
    }
               catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }

            }.resume()



        }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tests.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style : .default, reuseIdentifier : nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tests[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }




        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

     }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Post a code sample that compiles and runs. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think there's something wrong in the way you ask your question.

Comment: I got error data is not in the correct format in my struct Root, when I try to download  songs that plays right now from http://api.sr.se/api/v2/playlists/rightnow?format=json.

Comment: I tried running your code. The first problem is that it doesn't compile as-is, so I had to take a lot of guesses about how to get it to compile. The second problem is that I don't get the error you're talking about. Do yourself a big favor: follow the [guidelines for posting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help) by supplying a code sample that [compiles, runs, and demonstrates the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will be far more likely to get help.

Comment: Hi, the code above works for me to get all channels if you want it to work you need to allow arbitrary data in settings.

Comment: As I said before, the above code does not compile. Paste the real code. No one can help you if you post something else.

Comment: I have uploaded the full code now and its print out all of swedens radio channel. But I want it to print out every songs that plays right now and the previous for every channel. I need to use url http://api.sr.se/api/v2/playlists/rightnow? to download json data  and this http://api.sr.se/api/v2/playlists/rightnow?channelid=2576 for one radio channel.

Comment: Look at the data you're getting in the completion handler for `URLSession.shared.dataTask` -- it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Or, just click that last link you posted, and look at what your browser shows you.

Comment: I've updated my answer a couple of times as I've figured out more details on the problem. Be sure to look over it again wen you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

The data you're getting from `api.sr.se/api/v2/playlists/rightnow?format=json` does not always have the correct structure. Notice that sometimes you will get json that starts with a `copyright` field, while other times you get something like this:

```
{
    "playlist": {
        "previoussong": {
            "title": "Stir Fry",
            "description": "Migos - Stir Fry",
            "artist": "Migos",
            "composer": "Quavious Marshall/Pharrell Williams",
            "recordlabel": "Universal",
            "starttimeutc": "\/Date(1521137326000)\/",
            "stoptimeutc": "\/Date(1521137510000)\/"
        },
...
```

When you attempt to decode into `Root`, the decoder looks in the json for something that looks like your `Root` class, something like this:

```
{
    "copyright": "Copyright Sveriges Radio 2018. All rights reserved.",
    "channels": [{
        "id": 4540,
        "name": "Ekot",
        "playlists": {
            "playlist": {
                "channel": {
                    "id": 4540,
                    "name": "Ekot sÃ¤nder direkt"
                }
```

If it can't find something like that in the json, it says the data is missing. You will have to figure out a way to tell when to decode into `Root`, and when the data isn't appropriate for `Root`.

Comment: This is very good information, if correct, but saying "You will have to figure out..." risks making this not an actual answer. You might expand your explanation to show _how_ to try to decode into Root and how, if that fails, to detect that failure in good order and to try to decode into some other struct instead.

Comment: We differ. I have answered his question, *How do I fix my error?* to my own satisfaction. His error was believing the data is consistent. I'm a firm believer in helping someone who's stuck. I'm not so much a firm believer in what you're suggesting. He's obviously inexperienced; it would be a disservice to him to hand him a snippet of code; he will benefit far more from the experience of figuring that out for himself. If you feel differently, feel free to "help" him as you like. It's none of my business.

Comment: :) I'm not going to get involved further; he didn't even show his JSON, so I consider the entire question invalid.